Ошибка: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')
Я делаю пет-проект MEVN - сайт облачного хранилища.
При создания нового файла возникает ошибка в коде: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice').
Кусочек кода с ошибкой:
<div class="file__date">{{ file.date.slice(0, 10) }}</div>

Значение file.date получаю из пропса:
const props = defineProps({file: Object})

Модель файла с бэка:
const File = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    type: {type: String, required: true},
    accesLink: {type: String},
    size: {type: Number, default: 0},
    path: {type: String, default: ''},
    date: {type: Date, default: new Date()},
    user: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    parent: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'File'},
    childs: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'File'}]
})

Пробовал подобный метод - не помогло, вылез баг с отображением несуществующих файлов.
const date = props.file.date?.slice(0, 10) ?? '';

Хотел бы получить помощь в решении данной проблемы (или хотя бы указание направления решания данной проблемы).

Суть ошибки - file.date может и определена но точно не имеет метода slice. Если верить именам твоей переменной - там какая-то дата. А дата, в общем смысле, не есть строка. date: {type: Date, default: new Date()}, там объект типа "дата"...

Понял, буду капать в эту сторону, спасибо.

Более подробнее про ошибку, диагностику и способы устранения TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')

у вас ошибка возникает до появления данных в пропсе, либо задавайте дефолтное значение, либо обрабатывайте через computed/watch
